# c++ making a deep copy of a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, deep-copy

I am writing a program that does various operations with polynomials. The polynomial is a linked list made up of node objects. The object "Node" has two data members, m_coefficient and m_degree obviously being the coefficient and degree of each monomial. For the project I am given functions to implement. I have the default constructor which I believe I have correctly implemented.

```
Polynomial :: Polynomial(){
    Node *m_head = NULL;
}
```

Node *m_head is the only data member of the polynomial object.

I now have this which is supposed to be the copy constructor:

```
Polynomial :: Polynomial(const Polynomial& p)
```

How do I use this to make p a deep copy of the original linked list.

EDIT:

This is the Node class:

```
class Node {

public:

    Node();
    Node(long coeff, unsigned int deg);

    long m_coefficient;
    unsigned int m_degree;
    Node *m_next;
};
```

Comment: You can reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082586/coding-a-function-to-copy-a-linked-list-in-c

Comment: @Matthew Hanson You should show how the Node is defined.

Comment: You also need to implement the assignment operator and destructor, not just the copy constructor.

Comment: I have created a destructor and default constructor as well. But I have also added how the node class is set up if that helps

Comment: You've actually failed on the constructor by defining a local variable instead of assigning to the member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor can look the following way

```
Polynomial :: Polynomial(const Polynomial& p) : m_head( nullptr )
{
    Node **last = &m_head;

    for ( Node *current = p.m_head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        *last = new Node( current->m_coefficient, current->m_degree );
        ( *last )->m_next = nullptr;
        last = &( *last )->m_next;
    }
}
```

Also it is better to make class `Node` as an aggregate. For example

```
struct Node 
{
    long m_coefficient;
    unsigned int m_degree;
    Node *m_next;
};
```

In this case you could just write for example

```
*last = new Node { current->m_coefficient, current->m_degree, nullptr };
```

That is the constructor would look like

```
Polynomial :: Polynomial(const Polynomial& p) : m_head( nullptr )
{
    Node **last = &m_head;

    for ( Node *current = p.m_head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        *last = new Node { current->m_coefficient, current->m_degree, nullptr };
        last = &( *last )->m_next;
    }
}
```

And I think you mean

```
Polynomial :: Polynomial() : m_head( nullptr )
{
}
```

or

```
Polynomial :: Polynomial() 
{
    m_head = nullptr;
}
```

Otherwise you are initializing a local variable in the body of the constructor

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.

Comment: `Polynomial` does not have a member `m_head` ... I think you mean `p = m_head` also instead of the double pointer is it better to have a dummy `Node` and copythe list. At the end set m_head = `dummy.m_next`