# C++ Copy Constructor of Linked List's values, not addresses

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around pointers and linked lists. I can see that these types of questions are asked quite frequently here, so I apologize for adding to the mire of this forum. However,  I've been trying to wrap this assignment up for two days and I just can't seem to get it.

**I should point out that this is a homework assignment!**

I have a project wherein I have to copy a linked list, destroy the old list, and retain the values. I almost must pass to the copy constructor the entire list by reference, not just a node.

I've seen some really great responses already here after doing some digging, and the closest I've seen a solution to what I need to achieve is this one:

[Coding a function to copy a linked-list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082586/coding-a-function-to-copy-a-linked-list-in-c)

When I attempt to implement a similar code to mine, it give me this error upon compiling: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) linked list

Here's the code:

```
IntList::IntList(const IntList &a){
    if(a.head != NULL)
    {
            ListNode *thisNode = a.head;
            ListNode *nextN = NULL;

            while(thisNode != NULL)
            {
                    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
                    newNode->value = (*thisNode->value); //error occurs here

                    if(nextN == NULL)
                    {
                            nextN = newNode;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            nextN->next = newNode;
                            nextN = nextN->next;
                    }
                    thisNode = thisNode->next;
                    size++;
            }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The list empty." << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

If I remove the the encapsulation on line 10, the constructor doesn't issue an error. However, once I call the destructor, the old list still references the memory that has just been emptied out.

I truly appreciate any help on this assignment. I think I'm not dereferencing the pointer correctly, but I can't seem to break the code and get it to work...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You should use newNode->value = thisNode->value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 
    newNode->value = (*thisNode->value);
you need to 
    newNode->value = thisNode->value;

Comment: I started out doing that, but when I destroy the previous list, the new list's data isn't retained. I think newNode->value just points to the same address as thisNode->value. I'm not sure how to actually create a copy of the value and not just point to the same piece of memory.